# Magento 2 problem on xampp

Tags: magento2

I have installed magento 2 on latest xampp, Its installed without any error but when i am trying to access the frontend or backend its generate error. So when i checked under var/reports, There i found following error logs

```
 a:4:{i:0;s:46:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'mag2'";i:1;s:5315:"#0 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(332): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(861): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_connect()
#3 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(931): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->quote('default', NULL)
#4 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(1354): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->quoteInto('{{fieldName}} =...', 'default', NULL, NULL)
#5 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(2809): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->quoteInto('{{fieldName}} =...', 'default')
#6 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(2793): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_prepareQuotedSqlCondition('{{fieldName}} =...', 'default', '`scope`')
#7 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php(470): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->prepareSqlCondition('`scope`', 'default')
#8 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php(401): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->_getConditionSql('`scope`', 'default')
#9 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php(383): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->_translateCondition('scope', 'default')
#10 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\Scoped.php(59): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->addFieldToFilter('scope', 'default')
#11 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection.php(124): Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\Scoped->_initSelect()
#12 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\Scoped.php(48): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog), Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategy\Query), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy), NULL, Object(Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Data))
#13 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\Scoped->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog), Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategy\Query), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy), Object(Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Data), 'default', NULL, NULL)
#14 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(89): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Store\\M...', Array)
#15 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Store\\M...', Array)
#16 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\var\generation\Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\ScopedFactory.php(44): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('\\Magento\\Store\\...', Array)
#17 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\Config\Reader\DefaultReader.php(63): Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\ScopedFactory->create(Array)
#18 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config\ScopePool.php(84): Magento\Store\Model\Config\Reader\DefaultReader->read()
#19 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\module-backend\App\Config.php(41): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopePool->getScope('default', NULL)
#20 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\module-backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver.php(82): Magento\Backend\App\Config->getValue('admin/url/use_c...')
#21 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\module-backend\Helper\Data.php(206): Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver->getFrontName(false)
#22 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\module-backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor.php(46): Magento\Backend\Helper\Data->getAreaFrontName()
#23 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\var\generation\Magento\Backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor\Proxy.php(95): Magento\Backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor->process(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), '')
#24 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Request\Http.php(161): Magento\Backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor\Proxy->process(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), '')
#25 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request.php(194): Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http->setPathInfo()
#26 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Request\Http.php(204): Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request->getPathInfo()
#27 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(110): Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http->getFrontName()
#28 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#29 D:\xam\htdocs\mag2\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#30 {main}";s:3:"url";s:15:"/mag2/index.php";s:11:"script_name";s:15:"/mag2/index.php";}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You might try re-creating and double-checking your database information. Seems like you're trying to reference a database which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the database `mag2` doesn't exist. If you're interested I have a post on setting up with Vagrant.

http://brideo.co.uk/magento2/Installing-Magento-2-with-PuPHPet/

Comment: Its there and point is its installed well

Comment: So if you create a test script using the same database details can you connect?

Answer (score 0):

your "mag2" database is corrupted, i think some tables are not installed properly or you made some changes in innodb setting,  i also faced this problem but i created new DB and installed new.